# Can antimony pentafluoride be made by adding hydrogen fluoride to antimony trifluoride?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, experimental-chemistry, redox, synthesis

I was looking at how the strongest acid was made and I found something I did not understand. On the Wikipedia page for [antimony trifluoride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimony_trifluoride) it shows the production of $\ce{SbF3}$ using $\ce{HF}$:
$$\ce{Sb2O3 + 6 HF -> 2 SbF3 + 3 H2O}$$
The page also shows production of $\ce{SbF5}$ using $\ce{F2}$:
$$\ce{SbF3 + F2 -> SbF5}$$
However on the page for [fluoroantimonic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluoroantimonic_acid) it shows production of:

$$\ce{SbF5 + 2 HF -> SbF6- + H2F+}$$

So my question is why the production of $\ce{SbF5}$ seems to require fluorine insted of hydrogen fluoride? And is it possible to use hydrogen fluoride to make $\ce{SbF5}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It **can** be prepared using hydrogen fluoride, in a [double displacement reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimony_pentafluoride#Preparation):

> $\ce{SbCl5 + 5 HF -> SbF5 + 5 HCl}$

However, hydrogen holds onto fluorine more tightly than does antimony in $\ce{SbF5}$.

Consider the reverse of your proposed reaction, which is preferred energetically:

> $\ce{SbF5 + H2 -> SbF3 + 2HF}$

Comment: @EdV, sorry, I don't have that info. And, as you state, it's not something I'd try to measure. Does Derek Lowe have an article on SbF5, similar to this in his series *Things I Won't Work With* https://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2010/02/23/things_i_wont_work_with_dioxygen_difluoride?

Comment: @EdV, your welcome, but I have Wikipedia to thank.

Comment: so my takeaway is keep your Antimony pentafluoride away from your hydrogen.